# Gnome Desktop Graphic frozen/laggy after waking from sleep Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, gnome, suspend

I tried different kernels and nvidia-driver versions but after a wake up the desktop loads an dthen i can just move the mouse but nothing else.